# Remove header line in chapter opening (Context)

Tags: header-footer, context

I'd like to remove *only the header line*, and *only for chapter openings*, *but keeping the header at the chapter*. I know its not usual. Is there any way to do it automatically?

```
\setupheader
  [text]
  [before={\startframed[frame=off,bottomframe=on,framecolor=blue,]},
   after={\stopframed},
  ]
\setupheadertexts[Text left][Text right]
 
 
\starttext


%\setupheader
%  [text]
%  [before=,
%   after=,
%  ]
\chapter{asdf}

\page
%\setupheader
%  [text]
%  [before={\startframed[frame=off,bottomframe=on,framecolor=blue,]},
%   after={\stopframed},
%  ]
\section{asdf}

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2):

Dirty trick using [subpage numbers](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/magazines/mag-0002.pdf):

```
%For testing only
%\setuppapersize[A6]
\setupsubpagenumber[way=bychapter,state=start]
\startsetups zza
\doifelse{\the\numexpr\subpageno\relax}{1}{\startframed[frame=off]}{\startframed[frame=off,bottomframe=on,framecolor=blue,]}
\stopsetups
\setupheader
  [text]
  [before=\setup{zza},
   after=\stopframed,
  ]
\setupheadertexts[Text left][Text right] 
\starttext
\chapter{Dari balgeun bam...}
\dorecurse{3}{\samplefile{knuth}}
\chapter{Siltago malhae...}
\dorecurse{3}{\samplefile{tufte}}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Jairo, I guess not; I'd like to keep the header for the chapter, just eliminate the line.

Comment: @BlackBird See updated solution.